# How to time a session for a quiz (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, time

I am doing a quiz application and I would like to know what's the way to go about creating a timer for the quiz?

Currently I am going to display all the quiz questions on one page and have a main timer like 30minutes counting down and also to record the time taken when the user clicks submit.

In the future I might add in multipage quiz and also time taken for individual questions.

Any advice on what tools to use and structure would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: How "secure" do you need this to be?  If it doesn't matter, you can have some simple JavaScript and a hidden field on your quiz page.  But if you need to prevent "malicious" users from cheating, you'll have to do server-side validation.

Comment: understand. javascript should be sufficient for a start. it doesnt have to be so secure. can you point me towards an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a nice simple example, so I just wrote my own (tested in FF only):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="time" readonly="true"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        seconds = 0;

        function elapse()
        {
            seconds += 1;
            document.getElementById('time').value = seconds.toString();
        }

        setInterval(elapse, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll want to tweak it, probably:  If you don't want to show the elapsed time, you can use a hidden field; if you do, you'll want to format it a bit better.  But it's something to work with.

Hope that helps!